# WebStorm: show breadcrumbs on js file

Tags: javascript, webstorm, breadcrumbs

I want to know if there is a way to show breadcrumbs on js file.

Currently I only have the html one.

[image: html breadcrumbs]

What I want is the same that currently exists in Visual Studio (I don't know if it is a ReSharper thing or a native one)

[image: visual studio breadcrumbs]

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not yet supported for JavaScript

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7386 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

This needs to be implemented on per language basis.

PHP/HTML/CSS has it for ages. Java has it since last version (2016.2). Hopefully JavaScript will have it soon as well.